# Python re find index position of first search match

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a series of strings, most of which contain 4 digits in a row. I want to slice the string at the end of that fourth digit, using Python. Sometimes the string contains more than one such pattern. What I want is the index position of the FIRST match of my regular expression. What I have been able to get is the LAST match.

```
myString = 'Today is June 14, 2019. I sometimes like to think back when I was a child in 1730.'
theYear = re.compile("\d{4}")
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(theYear, myString)]

print m.span(0)
```

The result is (77, 81), which is the index position for the second date, not the first one. I know the problem is my loop, which will iterate through all of the matches, leaving me with the last one. But I havn't been able to figure out how to access those index positions without looping.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742287/finding-character-position-from-a-regexd-string

This shows proper usage of re.finditer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print theYear.search(myString).span()
```